# How to put chapter numbers on separate line with different formatting?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2016

I'm working on a Word template with different "chapters."

The layout looks like this:

1. Company logo page
2. Cover page (document title)
3. Cover letter
4. TOC
5. Chapter cover page (chapter number and heading 1)
6. Chapter contents (repeats chapter number and heading 1, may contain heading 2)
7. End page

Chapter contents (#6) may span multiple pages.
Obviously, there can be multiple chapters, so I have added a repeating content control around #5 and #6 to make it easier to duplicate the structure (as much as possible should be protected and not editable by the end user).

The problem is that the chapter cover page (#5) contains the chapter number on a different line and in a different formatting, like so:

[image: Chapter cover page]

This should then become 2.0, 3.0 etc. for other chapters.
The chapter contents (#6) then should use the data from the chapter cover page:

[image: Chapter contents]

The chapter contents copy the chapter title using `{STYLEREF "Heading 1"}`.
And I could make the numbering work by using a list style with hidden numbering for heading 1 (the chapter title) and regular numbering for the subsections (heading 2). This way, subsections are correctly numbered as 2.1, 2.2 etc. in other chapters.

But I can't make the chapter numbering work ("1.0" in this example):
I have tried with `{STYLEREF 1 \n}` - but it always returns "1" on the chapter cover page (#5), as if it doesn't pick up the heading 1 below.
As a quick fix, I have introduced a `SEQ` field, but those don't update automatically, so it's not ideal.

**How can I make the chapter numbering work?**
Obviously the heading 1 style is applied correctly, as the `STYLEREF` on the next page picks it up correctly.

Also, I struggle to make the TOC work.
I don't want any page numbers, only the structure, but this time with chapter numbers.
The best I could do was this:

[image: Table of contents]

Obviously, it should just be "1.0 Title for this chapter" and then "1.1 Subsection (heading 2)" below it.
But it looks like the heading 1 number does not get picked up because it is set to "hidden" in the list options...?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think I've understood you correctly and you want a result like this:

[image]

The distance between the "real" Heading number and the text is created by pressing Shift+Enter - new line instead of new paragraph. There's no way to get this automatically with a number format. (But you should be able to use paragraph formatting, as part of a style, for the StyleRef reflection of the Heading info.)

Take a look at the field codes as follows. Note especially StyleRef fields (2 of them!) with the \l switch to pickup the Heading from *below* rather than before.

[image]

To handle the numbering I created a new numbering style, linking the levels (I did only 2) with the Heading styles.

[image]